# SQL: alter table `familymembers` add constraint `familymembers_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `all_users` (`id`) in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I'm new to laravel.I trying to put foreign key in familymembers table.
but cannot migrate correctly.following error is occur. I trying so many different changes to solve the following error.but I cannot do it.This is not a duplicate question.plz..help me...

> In Connection.php line 647:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key
>   constraint
>
> ```
> (SQL: alter table `familymembers` add constraint `familymemb
>   ers_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `all_users` (`id`))
> ```
>
> In Connection.php line 449:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key
>   constraint

create_familymembers_table_migrations:

```
 Schema::create('familymembers', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('fullName');
                $table->string('relationship');
                $table->string('gender');
                $table->date('dob');

                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('all_users');

                $table->timestamps();

});
```

create_all_users_table_migrations:

```
Schema::create('all_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nameWithInitials');
            $table->string('callingName');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->integer('contactNo');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->string('addNo');
            $table->string('addStreet');
            $table->string('addCity');
            $table->string('intentToJoin');
            $table->string('region');

            $table->timestamps();
```

});

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which order are the migraton files? (By date). Did you create `all_users` **after** `familymembers`?

Comment: oh..really..I forgot about that.without original table can't create table with foreign key.I have less experience on laravel.I'm not consider date on the migration.Really thank you very much. I waste lot of time to solve this error.

Comment: Thats alright! Here to help. I've added as an answer so mark as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the migration files are in the right order.

e.g. `all_users` and then `familymembers`.